# Adding a class after completing the action

Tags: reactjs, class, addition

Good day.

I have a React Component. It's Navbar.

class Nav extends React.Component{

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }
    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    };

    handleScroll(event) {
      console.log('the scroll things', event)
    };

  render(){
    return(
      <div onScroll={this.handleScroll.bind(this)} className ="Nav">
        <Logo/>
        <Menu/>
      </div>

    )
  }
};
```

In constructor should bind every actions.
Later before component Mount adding EventListener is required.

If user take action `onScroll` I need to add class `.Nav Shadow`.

How can add class in `handleScroll` function with the simplest solutions?

Comment: Maintain a state variable for example shadowClass and in your handleScroll method set state of shadowClass to Nav_shadow

Comment: Ok it's working, but, I don't wan't to change class from a->b, only add class, so div should have a & b

Comment: Check if class is already present in the state variable and if it is present ignore it or add class as 'Nav_shadow '+this.state.shadowClass

Comment: handleScroll(event) {
      this.setState(
        {what here?}
      )

Comment: something like handleScroll(event) { 
let shadow = this.state.shadowClass 
this.setState( {shadowClass : shadow  + ' .Nav_shadow' } )

Comment: Now I have:
https://pastebin.com/0FkrTjJn

and error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NavClass' of null
    at Nav.handleScroll

Comment: Add this.state={NavClass: ''} in your constructor and check it once.

Comment: Now it's not error, but in finish the class isn't add

Comment: your className ='Nav' should be now className = {this.state.NavClass}

Comment: Ok, It's working I give to the constructor "Nav" and later setState to add Nav + Nav_Shadow

Thank you!

Where can I give U reputation?

Comment: Try className = `${this.state.Nav} Nav`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a state property in your constructor like

```
this.state={NavClass: 'Nav'}
```

In your handleScroll change it to

```
handleScroll(event) { 
    let shadow = this.state.shadowClass 
    this.setState({shadowClass : 'Nav_shadow' })
}
```

And refer this in your HTML as

```
className = `${this.state.Nav} Nav`
```